# Need a way to start web cam recording at specific time

Tags: video, webcam, cron, scripts

I have a laptop with an integrated camera and I want to write a script that will record a 10 minute video when the clock reaches a certain time. What apps/commands can I use to achieve this?

Comment: I am not sure about recording from command line, but you can use crontab to schedule it if you find a command to record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`streamer` will record from the command line.

```
sudo apt-get install streamer
```

This command will start and record for 10 seconds. You could start it with cron or with `scheduled tasks` from the repo:

```
  streamer -q -c /dev/video0 -f rgb24 -r 3 -t 00:00:10 -o /home/marc/outfile.avi
```

`man streamer` will tell you all you need to know.

Comment: how to record the sound as well ?

Comment: I'm in Montana, many hundreds of miles from home, and without time to fully test out my answer to you. Install `sox` from the command line, then type `man sox` for the manual. Should have everything you need.